# Removing extra plot using Matplotlib and Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, seaborn

I am wanting to produce a side by side plot showing a combined line and bar chart with 2 separate y axis on one plot, and a box plot on the other (the two charts are unrelated- different x and y axis). The code I run works absolutely fine. But it produces a separate, unwanted, empty plot underneath and I just cant figure out how to get rid of it. I have tried `fig.delaxes` but this only applies to subplots. And this appears to be a separate plot altogether. I have tried `display(fig)` and `fig.show()` but still this plain, empty chart shows up.

The code is the following:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matplotlib.rc_file_defaults()
ax1 = sns.set_style(style=None, rc=None )

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 2,figsize=(20,6))

g=sns.lineplot(data = Group['Value'], marker='o', sort = False, ax=ax1[0])
g=g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)

ax2 = ax1[0].twinx()

sns.barplot(data = Group, x='Variable 1', y='Variable 2', alpha=0.5, ax=ax2)
sns.catplot(x='Variable 3', y="Variable 1", data=Refined,kind="box",whis=100,ax=ax1[1])
```

Group is a dataframe that contains Variable 1, Variable 2 and Value.
Refined is a dataframe that contains Variable 1 and Variable 3.

Variable 1 is categorical, variable 2 and variable 3 are both numerical.

Probably very simple but this has just stumped me for ages. I just can't get rid of this additional empty plot underneath. Any help would be much appreciated- thanks!

Comment: You can't specify an `ax` when using a catplot, it is a figure level function (you should have seen a warning along the lines of `UserWarning: catplot is a figure-level function and does not accept target axes`). You might want to use a [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html#seaborn.boxplot) instead

Comment: Changed it to a boxplot and it worked. So simple- thanks